# SharePoint 2010, ASP.NET MVC integration

Tags: 2010, asp.net, mvc

As I previously posted [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69271/sharepoint-2010-asp-net-mvc-2)

I have to host an ASP.NET MVC 2 application on a SharePoint 2010 server. The application has to be hosted on the server, not referenced from a SP site.

So I've been searching the web for an answer on how to do that and i keep finding this [link](http://vspug.com/mbailey/files/2010/04/Using-ASP.NET-MVC-2-with-Sharepoint-Publishing.pdf) that doesn't exist anymore. Everything I tried was pieced from other solutions.
But I keep failing :(
I think one of the problems might be the windows authentication, i don't know how to make a MVC 2 app designed for intranet. (like the default templates for MVC 3 and 4)

Do you guys know any other tutorial for my problem ?
Or some pointers on how to do it.

Comment: By 'hosted on the server' do you mean that it has to have the same URL as SharePoint or that it merely needs access to SharePoint server objects?

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC is a completely different animal from SharePoint. For a start, SharePoint is built on ASP.NET WebForms.

If you want to migrate an app from MVC to SharePoint, your only option is to rebuild the app from scratch, using things SharePoint has to offer, such as Features, Lists, Workflows, etc.

If you have to merely host the MVC app on the SharePoint Server, then you may enter unsupported territory, as SharePoint performs a lot of maintenance on IIS, especially when it comes to multiple server environments. Trying to interfere with how SharePoint works on the file system manually will inevitably break your environment, as cumulative updates and hotfixes will blindly overwrite files within the SharePoint Root (14/15hive on the file system).

So basically, you have two options:

1. Rewrite the app from the ground up as SharePoint solution
2. Host your app on a separate server. Keep it away from SharePoint.